# unable to update terraform version

Tags: terraform, version, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

I already have the latest version in my provider.tf files:

```
  required_providers {
    archive = {
      source  = "hashicorp/archive"
      version = "2.2.0"
    }
    aws     = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.72.0"
    }
  }
```

However, when I check `terraform version`on my terminal, I get this:

```
Terraform v1.0.7
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.72.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.1.4. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

I already tried `terraform init -upgrade`but that didn't make a difference either.I also manually downloaded terraform's new version from the website but my terminal still shows 1.0.7.

Due to the old Terraform version, I face other errors. How can I update to the latest version using the terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between **providers** and **terraform** binary. With the command you are using you would update the **provider** and **module** versions. From your question I understand you downloaded the binary to your Mac. That of course is not enough. You have to replace the old binary with the new one. The easiest way to do this is to run:

```
echo $PATH
```

This should give you information about where to put the new binary so the system knows where to look for it. The output should look similar to:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Then subsequently run:

```
which terraform
```

It should show you where the `terraform` binary is located and in most cases it matches one of the locations listed in `PATH` environment variable. Example:

```
/usr/local/bin/terraform
```

Then, unzip the file you downloaded and copy it over to the location of the old binary. Note that this will delete the old version.

There are better ways to handle multiple terraform versions though. One of those is using `tfenv` [1].

Another way to install (and override) versions of terraform is to follow the guide here [2] and use `homebrew` which is MacOS' package manager, but in short the commands are:

```
brew tap hashicorp/tap
brew install hashicorp/tap/terraform
```

---

[1] https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv

[2] https://www.terraform.io/downloads

Comment: Well, the option you want to use is still not supported in the current provider version.

Comment: It works for my colleague...and it worked for me last time while on some other branch

Comment: I went through the docs and tried to find the block you are referencing and I can't find it. I think `3.72.0` is the latest.

Comment: I stand corrected, there is a new version and from what I see you got the answer you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to unlink `tfenv` and link `terraform` via `brew` to get the upgraded version (tested on mac m1).

Originally it was linked to previous installed version:

```
terraform -v

Terraform v1.5.6
on darwin_arm64

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.6.1. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

When I tried to upgrade via brew it said it was already updated to the latest:

```
brew upgrade terraform

Warning: hashicorp/tap/terraform 1.6.1 already installed
```

Solution with unlinking:

```
brew unlink tfenv
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/tfenv/3.0.0... 9 symlinks removed.
```

```
brew link terraform
Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/terraform/1.6.1... 1 symlinks created.
```

```
terraform -v
Terraform v1.6.1
on darwin_arm64
```

Hope it helps to anyone who is looking for solving similar issue.